# Factorial Question

Tags: math, probability

How come the number N! can terminate in exactly 1,2,3,4, or 6 zeroes by never 5 zeroes?

Comment: Suggest you ask at http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

The factors of 10 are 5 and 2.  Note that the 5th multiple of 5 will bring a pair of 5s into the product, which means you couldn't group just 5 5s as the factorials of 25+ have 6 fives within it.  Every even number contributes a 2 so that is where there are plenty of 2s to perform a sort of re-arranging of the prime factorization to get 10^6 within all factorials of 25 or higher.  Under 25, there are at most 4 factors that contain a 5: 5, 10, 15, and 20.

Comment: ...and there are always enough prime factors "2" to outnumber the "5"s, so the number of "5"s is the bottle neck.